# How to disable backdrop of angular material2's side nav?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'am new to angular material. I want to know how to disable backdrop of side nav. Here is the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y5R7WqliF9M98g7LY0x8?p=preview) with the backdrop not disabled.

**what i tried**
code:

```
<mat-sidenav md-disable-backdrop  #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
    Under construction!
</mat-sidenav>
```

Answer (score 4):

try adding this to your global stylesheet(styles.scss or styles.css) in your project:

```
.mat-drawer-backdrop.mat-drawer-shown {
    background: none;
}
```